# How can I use a button to terminate a python script on Raspberri Pi midway through its execution?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Using a Raspberry Pi, I have built a device which queries an API, and then sets of an alarm and some (very annoying) flashing lights if the API returns a different result ID to the previous call.

For the purposes of illustration, let's say the API returns a DM from a social media platform.

I also have a button, and I would like to use the button to terminate the entire process if it's inconvenient for an alarm and some (very annoying) flashing lights to be going off at that particular time (eg I'm in a meeting).

However, I'm not especially experienced with Python, and I'm struggling to understand how I can interrupt the script mid-way through it's execution.

Can anyone advise of a way in which I could detect a button push, using the GPIO input, and stop the device from playing audio and flashing its lights?

Here's the code I've got so far. In the interests of brevity I've stripped out anything which isn't essential to the question at hand.

```py
# (dependencies have been imported)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)


# get the latest API response and store it

response = requests.get('api.call?params')
messageID = response['result'][0]['id']


# loop the query

try:
  while True:
    
    time.sleep(30)
    
    response = requests.get('api.call?params')
    data = response['result'][0]

    
    # if it's a new message, set off the alarm

    if(data['id'] != messageID): 
      messageID = data['id']

      fanfare = AudioSegment.from_mp3('fanfare.mp3')
      
      
      # turn on lights

      GPIO.output(26, False)
      GPIO.output(21, False)
      GPIO.output(20, False)

      play(fanfare)

      # Here is where I'm having the problem
      # I'm not sure how I can stop the fanfare
      # And skip to the lights being turned off (below),
      # or invoke a function that does so

      GPIO.output(26, False)
      GPIO.output(21, False)
      GPIO.output(20, False)
```

Comment: You're probably looking at polling the pin either periodically or in another thread. You could also look at interrupts https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/#wait_for_edge-function

Comment: So, carrying on from @fdcpp'sxsuggestion, in your interrupt callback or polling thread, set a variable `alertSuppressed=true`. Then change your `if` statement to `if (data['id'] != messageId)) && !alertSuppressed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you would like the music to stop playing when you press the button. In order to do that, you'll probably want to use something other than `pydub.playback` for playing the music. I would suggest [`pygame`](https://www.pygame.org/news), which has facilities to start/pause/unpause/stop playing music from an MP3 file; e.g:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('fanfare.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

It would be convenient to wrap your "alarm" functionality into a class; we can have class methods for starting and stopping the alarm that handle both the LEDs and the music. Maybe something like this:

```
import threading
import time
import pygame

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Alarm:
    def __init__(self, led_pins, music):
        self.led_pins = led_pins
        self.music = music
        self.active = False
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.music)

    def _raise_alarm(self):
        for pin in self.led_pins:
            GPIO.output(pin, 1)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        self.active = True
        t_alarm = threading.Thread(target=self._raise_alarm, daemon=True)
        t_alarm.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.active = False
        for pin in self.led_pins:
            GPIO.output(pin, 0)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

When you call the `start` method, this turns on the LEDs and starts playing music in a background thread. After the music finishes playing, it will turn off the LEDs. You can also stop it prematurely by calling the `stop` method.

We can see how that works with code like (assuming the above code is in `alarm.py`):

```
import alarm
import pygame
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

pygame.mixer.init()

a = alarm.Alarm([4], 'fanfare.mp3')
a.start()
input("press RETURN to stop the alarm")
a.stop()
```

Next, we need to integrate button detection into your main loop. One way to do that is with the `GPIO.add_event_detect` and `GPIO.event_detected` methods, which you can use to asynchronously detect the button press. We can do something like this:

```
while True:

    time.sleep(check_interval)

    new_message_id = get_message_id()
    if new_message_id != last_message_id:
        print("START ALARM")
        alarm.start()
        last_message_id = new_message_id
        GPIO.add_event_detect(button_pin, GPIO.FALLING)

        while alarm.active:
            if GPIO.event_detected(4):
                print("STOP ALARM")
                alarm.stop()
            time.sleep(0.1)

        GPIO.remove_event_detect(button_pin)
```

While the alarm is active, we loop watching for the button. If the button is pressed, we cancel the alarm immediately.

Putting that all together, we get:

```
# Support pygame support message
import os
os.environ["PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT"] = "1"

import pygame
import requests
import threading
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from alarm import Alarm

button_pin = 4
led_pin = 17
music_file = "fanfare.mp3"
endpoint_url = "http://localhost:8000/endpoint"
check_interval = 10

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(button_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)


# This probably needs updating for your particular API
def get_message_id():
    res = requests.get(endpoint_url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return res.json()["value"]


def main():
    pygame.mixer.init()

    # I only have a single LED handy, but you would presumably
    # update this to use multiple pins.
    alarm = Alarm([led_pin], music_file)
    last_message_id = get_message_id()

    while True:
        time.sleep(check_interval)

        new_message_id = get_message_id()
        if new_message_id != last_message_id:
            print("START ALARM")
            alarm.start()
            last_message_id = new_message_id
            GPIO.add_event_detect(button_pin, GPIO.FALLING)

            while alarm.active:
                if GPIO.event_detected(4):
                    print("STOP ALARM")
                    alarm.stop()

            GPIO.remove_event_detect(button_pin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can find all the code referenced in this answer at https://github.com/larsks/rpi-alarming-example